# Column as list with comma between

Tags: mysql, sql, select

How can I query a database that has the following columns : `id`, `name`. With the result having column 'name' rows displayed as list?

```
Id Name
1 name1
2 name2
3 name3
4 name4

Result: name1,name2,name2,name4
```

Currently my query looks like this

```
SELECT name FROM banned
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Strawberry I have banned words inside a table and want to compare against a Twitter API

Comment: @Alex_TNT So is a string better than an array in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function should do the trick:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY name) AS name
FROM   banned
```

EDIT:
To answer the question in the comment, you could add a `separator` clause to replace the comma in the result:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY name SEPARATOR '...') AS name
FROM   banned
```

Comment: Thank you, seems to work, any way I could change the comma with something else inside the query? If not this is ok, I'll accept this as answer in 10min

Comment: @Alex_TNT sure - just add a `separator` clause. I've edited my answer to include the details.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
DISTINCT Name
ORDER BY Name
SEPARATOR ',' )
FROM banned;

Answer (score 0):

[use SEPERATOR KEYWORD IN GROUP_CONCAT FUNCTION](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0mCa.png)